# trying to use angular-ui-bootstrap radiobutton directive with ng-repeat in an angular project

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui-bootstrap

So... I'm trying to generate a radiobutton group using ng-repeat:

```
<div class="btn-group yb-radiobuttons">
    <button type="button" class="btn" ng-model="radioModel" btn-radio="'all'">All locations ({{dreamboxItemsByDate.length}})</button> 
    <button type="button" class="btn" data-ng-repeat="(key, value) in items" ng-model="radioModel" btn-radio="'{{key}}'">{{key}} ({{value.length}})</button>
</div>
```

this generates the following html:

```
<div class="btn-group yb-radiobuttons">
    <button class="btn ng-pristine ng-valid ng-binding" btn-radio="'all'" ng-model="radioModel" type="button">All locations (10)</button>
    <button class="btn ng-scope ng-valid ng-binding ng-dirty active" btn-radio="'Brooklyn, New York'" ng-model="radioModel" data-ng-repeat="(key, value) in items" type="button"> Brooklyn, New York (6) </button>
    <button class="btn ng-scope ng-valid ng-binding ng-dirty active" btn-radio="'London, UK'" ng-model="radioModel" data-ng-repeat="(key, value) in items" type="button"> London, UK (2) </button>
    <button class="btn ng-scope ng-pristine ng-valid ng-binding" btn-radio="'Tokyo, Japan'" ng-model="radioModel" data-ng-repeat="(key, value) in items" type="button"> Tokyo, Japan (2) </button>
</div>
```

that looks all good on first sight, however clicking on any of the button elements generated with repeat doesn't set the model at all - only click on the button for all locations sets the model.

plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/J1LfRO?p=preview

Any ideas why this is happening / how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn" data-ng-repeat="(key, value) in items" ng-model="radioModel" btn-radio="key">{{key}} ({{value.length}})</button>
```

Notice `btn-radio="key"`, just drop `{{}}` and `''`

Comment: Nice try! Unfortunately this doesn't work. It compiles into: <button class="btn ng-scope ng-valid ng-binding ng-dirty active" btn-radio="key" ng-model="radioModel" data-ng-repeat="(key, value) in items" type="button"> London, United Kingdom (3) </button>

Comment: @Dine it doesn't matter to what it compiles, really. Could you send A plunk with your code? http://plnkr.co/

Answer (score 0):

What about using this snippet :

```
<button type="button" class="btn" ng-repeat="(city, message) in items" ng-model="radio.model"     btn-radio="city">{{city}} ({{message}})</button>
```

jsFiddle working here : http://jsfiddle.net/Stego/fvDcS/